# How to access state of Producer connection in Route from CamelContext

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a route which looks like the following:

```
from("seda:in")
    .routeId("aggregation")
    .process(filterProcessor)
    .aggregate(header("flag", new MyAggregationStrategy())
    .completionInterval(10000)
    .multicast()
    .to(sftpUris);
```

I'd like to be able to access the producers for each of the URIs in the `to` clause and check the status of the SFTP connection.

So far I haven't worked out a way of doing this for single (non-multicast) producer, so solutions to that would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html), you should look at the `CamelFtpReplyCode` header (and perhaps `CamelFtpReplyString`) to determine what happened with the request. By default, FTP errors do **NOT** raise an exception.

Comment: The aim is to be able to check the status to find out if the connection has come back up after a period of downtime. And to do this before sending anything through the camel route.

Comment: You want to connect to **all** the sftp locations, ensure that the connection is successful, and then route the data to **all** destinations at the same time?

Comment: kind of, if one of the connections is succesfull, then I'm happy to send data to all destinations and accept failures at the others

Comment: Then could you try to write to all the destinations? You could look and see the results of all the attempts and take some action. If they all failed, then that's not actually changed anything and you can retry without penalty.

Comment: That's what I'm trying currently, I was looking for a method that would avoid that, preferably by calling a getStatus method on the connection. But it doesn't seem to be accessible

Comment: The connection isn't really available for you to see, as the Camel component is managing that for you. If you need such a fine level of control you may have to write your own bean, but that doesn't seem worth it.